# React Antdesign performance optimisation

Tags: reactjs, antd

It seems that change in one antd component, will trigger rerender for all other Components on the page. `React.PureComponent` doesn't work, when you put antdesign components inside - it won't allow to enter text, because no state and props changed.

The only workaround i see, is putting extra logic inside `shouldComponentUpdate`, or maintain local state with `onChange` method for every single field.

Maintaining state for all fields, is a headache for me. Does anyone run large app with many antdesign items, so that i could at least understand when is the right time to make optimisations?

Currently i have forms with about 60 antdesign components, and when typing, it hangs for a while.

Comment: _React.PureComponent doesn't work_... Could you elaborate on why you think it doesn't work for you? If possible, with a small working example?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb sorry, i think ```React.PureComponent``` will work, if state is set for each antd component with ```onChange``` callback. But it doesn't allow to easily trigger component update, when parent state changes. In ```shouldComponentUpdate```, it is easy to check for any scenario, coming from a parent prop or state, and ignore the rest

Answer (score 0):

As no one answered, i'll post answer, which i came up with, while experimenting. 
It seems that using `shouldComponentUpdate` combined with local state and parent state, if needed, is the way to go.

On each field i've attached `onChange` event to change local state on the component. Then inside `shouldComponentUpdate` check if nextState equals to current state.

If you also need to check something against parent state, pass it through props.

Personally i don't like this approach, but can't think of anything better. 
If you feel like there is a better way, i'll be glad to hear a different opinion.